# Setting headers in HttpClient for authorizing a rest api

Tags: c#, http-headers, httpclient

I successfully authenticated when using Postman, but using HttpClient in c#, I'm not able to login. So my syntax are not correct I presume. Any help in the right direction are much welcome.

[image: Postman]

```
        private static HttpClient _httpClient = new() { Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0) };

        public BaseRepository()
        {

            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-AppSecretToken", "xxx");
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-AgreementGrantToken", "xxx");
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        }
```

Comment: Can you share the whole blueprint of the BaseRepository class ?

Comment: @Orenico There are many classes, as I made it very generic. But I can just quickly make a console application and share that code.

Comment: I am asking cause you might have some initialization issue there is a static field and I see a base non parameter constructor and I assume you don't have a static constructor that might cause some ambiguities when you initialize objects from this class, do you have any exception thrown ?

Comment: Your correct, after dropping the static keyword it authenticated me. Problem solved, I'll read up on a good pattern for the initialization of httpclient

Comment:  this is a good place to get some best practices using the HttpClient
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Thanks, using IHttpClientFactory is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

since you are using custom tokens you can have some validation problems. try this

```
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("X-AppSecretToken", "xxx");
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("X-AgreementGrantToken", "xxx");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out
`_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =  new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "token");`
It worked in my project